# Ошибка загрузки файла yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

В ЧЕМ ПРОБЛЕМА!? УЖЕ второй день не могу понять, вроде все верно..

МОДЕЛЬ:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use app\models\ArticleFile;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "article".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $desc
 * @property string $text
 * @property string $date
 * @property int $category_id
 * @property int $status
 *
 * @property Comment[] $comments
 */
class Article extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $imageFile;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'article';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['desc', 'text'], 'string'],
            [['date'], 'safe'],
            [['category_id', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'jpg'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'desc' => 'Desc',
            'text' => 'Text',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'category_id' => 'Category ID',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'imageFile' => 'Photos',
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->imageFile->saveAs('2018/allim/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['article_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Article */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="article-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'desc')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'text')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {



        $model = new Article();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {


                $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');

                if ($model->upload() && $model->save()) {

                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

                }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выводит?

Comment: в модели при вызове `saveAs` надо указывать полный путь